# Could "trotzdem" be used instead of "obwohl"?

Tags: difference, conjunction

Can I use *trotzdem* instead of *obwohl*? For example:

> 1. Trotzdem er krank war, ging er noch zur Arbeit.
> 2. Obwohl er krank war, ging er noch zur Arbeit.

Comment: obwohl and trotzdem don't really have similar enough meanings to compare. The first one says "Despite the fact he was sick, he still went to work" and the second one says "Although he was sickly/ailing, he still went to work" (I think you may be using kränklich, in a manner that assumes a meaning different than the one you intended). This sentences have similar meanings, but are not exact enough to compare, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, you can. See meaning 2 here: https://www.dwds.de/wb/trotzdem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Agreeing with *thekeyofgb*'s comment, it is not apparent that they are similar. But in used in their right place, they convey the same effect:

> 1. Er war krank. Trotzdem ging er zur Arbeit.
> 2. Obwohl er krank war, ging er zur Arbeit.

There is a third (at least) possibility *trotz+(`Genitiv`)* (with `Dativ` is used in [Switzerland](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/trotz) more often)

> Trotz seiner Krankheit ging er zur Arbeit.

or

> Er ging trotz seiner Krankheit zur Arbeit.

According to [wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/trotzdem) the order you put the sentence in, is also allowed, but it is *umgangssprachlich*:

> Trotzdem  er krank war, ging er zur Arbeit. (*umg.* and pronounced [tʀɔʦˈdeːm])

I must say that I've never heard the *trotzdem* in this subjunctional use. The pronunciation remark, added by Emanuel, is that the second syllable should be stressed if *trotzdem* is intended with this meaning (opposite to  [ˈtʀɔʦdeːm], the adverb.)

Comment: If we use *noch* we need to explain why we use it. As it is now, we should better leave it out.

Comment: @takkat i thought trotzdem was used in formal registers because Thomas Mann always used it in his writings.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 both *trotzdem*, and *obwohl* are common but with trotzdem you need a reason to come before, with *obwohl* the reason comes after it.

Comment: The difference between the normal "trotzdem" (adverb) and the verb last one "subord. Conj." is stress... TROTZdem vs. trotzDEM. If this stress is not made clearly, people will not understand the "trotzdem" to be the second one and the sentence will sound wrong and change the meaning. I have my doubts as to whether it is umgangssprachlich but that aside, I'd recommend adding the stress-part to the answer as it is really really crucial

Comment: I definitely hear *trotzdem* used as in the last example. It would classify it as wrong, but it may be common regionally.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, *trotzdem*  is used far less as a conjunction and the alternatives using the adverb or the preposition *trotz* seem more standard/usual.  I looked this up only because I am being asked to correct a translation from a slightly bastardised English "Yesterday my school day was wonderful, *although* we had a test in physics."  We wouldn't necessarily say *although* in English here, it sounds awkward.  If you use *obwohl* for *although*, it is like a return serve, taking something away from the wonderful day.  If you use *trotzdem* it sounds as if any negative impact of the test was overcome and of little consequence.  I am not sure what the English intends, but *although* sounds somewhat awkward to me.  I agree with the above where it states the *obwohl* clause ususally comes first, and in this case it renders the meaning of *trotzdem*!  Gestern war mein Schultag toll, *obwohl* wir in Physik eine Klassenarbeit geschrieben haben.  *Obwohl wir in Physik eine Klassenarbeit geschrieben haben, war mein Schultag gestern toll.  Gestern war mein Schultag toll, trotzdem wir eine Klassenarbeit geschrieben haben*.  Have a think.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different words. "Trotzdem" means "nevertheless," while "obwohl" means "although."

Surprisingly, they can be used somewhat "interchanageably," because they are complementary.

The basic sentence would be:  "*Obwohl* er krank war, ging er *trotzdem* noch zur Arbeit."  Although he was sick, he nevertheless went to work.

Two similar example sentences can then be formed by omitting one or the other, which shows their complementarity, by "interchanging" them.

> 1. *Obwohl* er krank war, ging er noch zur Arbeit. (Omit trotzdem.)
> 2. Er war krank; *trotzdem* ging er noch zur Arbeit. (Omit obwohl.)