# Different meanings from different accentuation rules

Tags: meaning, phonetics

On this site I recently read that it was possible, that the meaning of a word could change if you change the stressed syllable. The example was:

> [trotz-'dem] meaning *altough* (as *obwohl* colloquial use)

compared to

> ['trotz-dem] meaning *however*.

- Are there other words changing their meaning, if the accent is changed?

I've heard, for instance *['wa-rum]* and *[wa-'rum]* or *[des-'we-gen]* and *['des-we-gen]* but I'm not able to distinguish if this is a normal difference due to regional accents or they have different meanings.

Comment: I think you'll be better of distinguishing by context compared to accentuation

Comment: I don't use *trotzdem* in the sense of *obwohl*, so I would certainly pronounce it incorrectly if this is true what you're saying ;)

Comment: @Em1 then I didn't understand Emanuel's comment [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9144/could-trotzdem-be-used-instead-of-obwohl/9145#9145): "The difference between the normal "trotzdem" (adverb) and the verb last one "subord. Conj." is stress... TROTZdem vs. trotzDEM. If this stress is not made clearly, people will not understand the "trotzdem" to be the second one and the sentence will sound wrong and change the meaning."

Comment: He might be correct. But I tend to agree with adibender that context is more important than pronunciation. As said, I don't use this word in the "obwohl"-sense, so I wouldn't realise a different pronunciation.

Comment: The trotzdem-although use is incredibly rare. That's why it is sooo crucial to do the stress. Otherwise people's grammar brain will make false assumptions which it then has to reevaluate when the verb doesn't come and then everyone is like "What? What structure is that?" ... the "trotzDEM" mimics the "obWOHL"... don't know if that is the only reason but it might be

Comment: possible duplicate of [Welche deutschen Wörter unterscheiden sich nur in der Betonung?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1458/welche-deutschen-w%c3%b6rter-unterscheiden-sich-nur-in-der-betonung)

Comment: @c.p. Emmanuel’s assertion that there is such usage is correct. I cannot say where I heard it, but it is certainly familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the difference you are aluding to exists, e.g.

> "`TrotzDEM` ich starke Kopfschmerzen hatte, bin ich zum Training gegangen."
>   (i.e. in the meaning of `trotzdessen`, or `obwohl` as you said)

vs.

> "Ich hatte starke Kopfschmerzen, `TROTZdem` bin ich zum Training gegangen."
>   (here you could use `nichtsdestotrotz`instead, or also `trotzdessen`, contrary to `trotzdem` you wouldn`t make a difference in accentuation though).

The first usage however is quite antiquated and isn't used often in today's german. 
As for a part of your question, if someone uses it that way (or other words for which such a difference exists), you'll probably catch the difference rather intuitively based on context and sentence structure (altough the differnce in accentuation is there too). I think catching it based on accentuation alone would be difficult (depending on dialect etc.) even for native speakers. I agree with @Emanuell's comment however that the it will sound weird in the first example if you use the second accentuation.

Right now I can't think of another (more modern) example of a word that has different meaning based on accentuation, but I'll try to think of something...