# Usage differences of “obwohl” and “trotzdem”

Tags: difference, conjunction

I’m confused with *obwohl* and *trotzdem* usage practice. I do know their meaning (*although* and *despite of*, respectively) but what I don’t understand is when exactly I should use *obwohl*, when *trotzdem* and when I can exchange them?

The problem is that English is not my native language either, thus the simple rule: “if you would use *although* in English put *obwohl* in German” doesn’t really help me, I don’t feel which of them should I use.

For instance:

> 1. Clarissa bleibt nicht im Bett, ***obwohl*** sie krank ist.

versus

> 2. Clarissa bleibt nicht im Bett, ***trotzdem*** ist sie krank.

Are both these sentences OK both from the grammatical and style points of view?
Or should I use only one of them?

Could you, please, clarify how I can understand which of these two connection words I should use?

P.S. I read the [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9144/could-trotzdem-be-used-instead-of-obwohl) and this [explanation](http://deutsch.info/en/grammar/obwohl) but still feel that I’m guessing and don’t really know for sure the correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a somewhat uneasy subject to digest. I try my best to explain based on the [Duden](http://www.duden.de).

Taking your example the first is fine and *obwohl* can be replaced by *trotzdem*; though *obwohl* is more often used and considered high-level language. In this case *obwohl* and *trotzdem* are **conjunctions**. The usage of *trotzdem* in this case is considered colloquial language (umgangssprachlich).

> Clarissa bleibt nicht im Bett, obwohl sie krank ist.
>   Clarissa bleibt nicht im Bett, trotzdem sie krank ist.

The second sentence is correct. Though many German speakers would say that it sounds weird to them.
I suggest you use *obwohl* when not sure and because it is not colloquial.

---

There is another meaning of *obwohl*, which is colloquial, and cannot be replaced by *trotzdem*.

> Ich rufe Dich heute Abend an. Obwohl, wir sehen uns ja morgen ohnehin.
>   I call you this evening. Though, we'll see each other tomorrow anyway.

Here it is used to say that *Maybe I call, maybe I don't; knowing that we see each other tomorrow anyway*.

---

The word *trotzdem* can also be used as an **adverb**. That can be confusing for speakers. This is how you used the word *trotzdem* in the second example and in this case it is wrong by meaning; you are not saying what you want to say.

> Clarissa bleibt nicht im Bett, trotzdem ist sie krank.
>   Clarissa doesn't want to stay in bed, nevertheless she is sick.

When *trotzdem* is used as an adverb it does not have the same meaning as *obwohl*. In this case *trotzdem* could be translated to *even so*, *anyhow*, *nevertheless*, ...

Comment: I wouldn’t call the use of _trotzdem_ as a conjunction “colloquial”. Thomas Mann is infamous for it, and his writings are far from colloquial language. It is a mannerism, and one many native speakers react strongly negatively to.

Comment: Apart from that, I don’t think this answer will be particularly useful to the OP because it essentially only explains the meaning of _trotzdem_ by giving English equivalents, and the OP already said he doesn’t have a firm grasp of those either.

Comment: In the Duden it is mentioned that its usage as a conjunction is colloquial.

Comment: And I think I gave a fairly good answer to his questions: grammar, style point of view, which one to use preferably and background with reference to the Duden.

Comment: In your second example *„Clarissa bleibt nicht im Bett, trotzdem sie krank **ist**”* the verb is at the end of the sentence. Is it correct? I read that ***trotzdem*** requires the verb at the second place. Could you, please, clarify the case.

Comment: According to the Duden it is a correct usage. It is colloquial language. That is because *trotzdem* is used in place of *obwohl*, as a conjunction. An example can be found at this link http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/trotzdem_obzwar_wenngleich - section **Bedeutungsübersicht**: *er kam, trotzdem (standardsprachlich: obwohl) er krank war*

Comment: @Mike B.: If _trotzdem_ is used as a conjunction, it introduces a subordinate clause, so the verb comes last. In the normal use (as an adverb), the usual rules for the sentence containing it apply. Examples: *Ich verreise trotzdem.* (main clause) *Wir können für nichts garantieren, falls er trotzdem verreist.* (subordinate clause)

Comment: I’d recommend forgetting about the possible use of _trotzdem_ as a conjunction at this point.

Comment: @chirlu, is it colloquial? Or stilted?

Comment: @Dan: Stilted. I never hear it in everyday talk (but can’t rule out that it may be used in some region).

Comment: @chirlu, bedankt. Ich habe gerade übrigens das "nun" auch als Konjunktion entdeckt. Was "obwohl" angeht, ist es echt überraschend wie viele gehobene Synonyme es gibt. Obschon, obgleich, trotzdem...

Answer (score 12):

First, your grammar, in particular your word order is correct. But I think that the meaning of the second sentence is not what you thought. The first is ok.

> A, obwohl B

means that both A and B are true, and it points out that in particular B did not prevent A from being true, even though it should in general, or one might think that it does, or it usually does, or something.

Your first sentence thus means: Clarissa is ill. She did not stay in bed. It also conveys that Clarissa should have stayed in bed, because she is ill, or maybe, that it is commendable that she did not let her illness prevent her from getting up.

The same is expressed by:

> B. Trotzdem A.

So the above meaning could also have been expressed by:

> Clarissa ist krank. Trotzdem ist sie nicht im Bett geblieben.

(Clarissa trotzte also ihrer Krankheit, indem sie nicht im Bett blieb.)

Your second sentence, on the other hand, says that Clarissa is ill and did not stay in bed, and that that is surprising, since usually getting up prevents you from getting ill. Or, more reasonably as chirlu pointed out, it emphasises that she is really ill, even though her not staying in bed might indicate that she is not.

Comment: The parenthesized sentence seems somewhat out of place to me. It is an explanation, so shouldn’t it be in English?

Comment: @chirlu, the parenthesised sentenced was meant as an invitation to look up the related verb *trotzen*.

Comment: @CarstenS what would you say about the "conjunctional" usage of "trotzdem"? https://german.stackexchange.com/a/27435/9739

Answer (score 3):

In case of *trotzdem*, the conjugated verb stays at 2nd position as it's mostly used adverbially, but in case of *obwohl*, the conjugated verb goes in the end.

For example:

> Obwohl ich krank **bin**, bin ich in die Schule gekommen. / Ich bin in die Schule gekommen, obwohl ich krank **bin**.
>
> Ich bin in die Schule gekommen, trotzdem **bin** ich krank.

(Note that in case of trotzdem, the position of conjugated verb is at 2nd position.
Additionally, it cannot be written the other way around.)

Comment: Uh! Please, notice that _in **der** Schule kommen_ means something totally different than _in **die** Schule kommen_.

Comment: Was Bjönrn sagt. In der Schule kann man ankommen (en. arrive at), aber nicht kommen.

Comment: @Dan: Man kann auch _in der Schule kommen_, aber es bedeutet dann _in der Schule einen Orgasmus haben_ ([Bedeutung 17](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kommen)).

Comment: @chirlu, ja stimmt. Und im Englischen kann man auch "high" sein.

Comment: @chirlu, man kann auch einfach "Schule kommen" und somit das Dilemma loswerden ;)

Comment: Note that the logic in the _obwohl_ example sentences here is inverted. *Krank, obwohl Schule* implies that going to school should somehow have protected from the (later) illness.

Comment: @chirlu "Additionally, you can start a sentence with obwohl, but that’s not the case with trotzdem. " echt jetzt? Ist das eine Stilsache wie mit "und", oder?

Comment: @Dan: Nein, geht sehr gut. *Sie ist krank. Trotzdem ist sie in die Schule gekommen.*

Comment: @chirlu, meine Rede. Habe die Antwort korrigiert.

Comment: thanks to all for correcting me...

Comment: And the reason for "obwohl" being in the end, is that "trotzdem" is used in a "Hauptsatz" and "obwohl" in a "Nebensatz".

Answer (score 0):

Per Duden *trotzdem* is an adverb. In the German language, some adverbs are also used as connectors, for example, *trotzdem, jedoch, deshalb, deswegen*, etc. However, when these adverbs are used as connectors, the verb position must still be placed at position 2 instead of at the end (this differs from conjunctions such as *obwohl, weil, damit,* ...).

This use of adverbs as connectors does not exist in English language. In English, only conjunctions can connect sentences with a comma and never only an adverb.

The correct sentences are:

> Clarissa bleibt nicht im Bett, trotzdem ist sie krank.

--> verb cannot be at the end.

> Clarissa bleibt nicht im Bett, obwohl sie krank ist.

--> verb must be at the end.

Trotzdem and obwohl do not have the same meanings:
trotzdem: nevertheless.
obwohl: although.

Comment: @user unknown: the reason to write 'Konnektoren' instead of 'connectors' is because in English we do not have 'connectors' in the grammatical sense. It is somewhat misleading to translate it. Thank you for your editing but the downvoting is not helpful.

Comment: The statement *"[...] when these adverbs are used as connectors, the verb position must still be placed at position 2 instead of at the end [...]"* is wrong for two reasons. (1) Depending on its function, *trotzdem* can be either *adverb* or *connector*, but not both at the same time. Thus, the first part of the quote does not make sense. (2) I could present various examples from Thomas Mann, Hermann Hesse, Theodor Fontane, Stefan Zweig and certainly others that disprove the second part of the quote.

Comment: Duden (a German dictionary considered to be official by most teachers and editors) lists trotzdem only as an adverb. Any disagreement on that should be communicated to Duden. As said, trotzdem (same as a few other adverbs) can be used as an adverb or a 'connector'. When it is used as a 'connector', after a comma it is usually placed at position 1 in a 'Satz' (Hauptsatz or Nebensatz, depending on the naming custom), the verb is always at position 2 instead of at the end (which is the case for weil, wenn, ...)

Comment: There is nothing to communicate to DUDEN. Entry **trotzdem** in DUDEN 2, 10th ed., p. 896: „**trotzdem** <Konj.> (ugs.): *obwohl*: t. es regnete, gingen sie spazieren.“ ...

Comment: ... Entry **trotzdem** in DUDEN 9, 8th ed., pp. 921–922: „**trotzdem**: Im heutigen Sprachgebrauch wird *trotzdem* als [satzeinleitendes] Adverb wie auch als untergeordnete Konjunktion verwendet [...] Die Verwendung von *trotzdem* als untergeordnete Konjunktion ist bereits im 19. Jh. aufgekommen [...] *Und trotzdem diese Situation mir selber lästig war, trotzdem ich mich auf alle mögliche Weise anstrengte, ernst zu sein, kam das Lachen stoßweise immer wieder* (Rielke).“

Comment: Duden Bedeutungswörterbuch 4. Auflage: trotzdem is adverb. As said, in German a few adverbs can be used as 'connectors', such as deshalb, jedoch, deswegen, darum, .... Thank you for showing this example. The problem is when a German language lerner goes into a Telc or Goethe test and write a sentence like this one, likely they will lose points. Send the example to a professional editor and see what they say.

Comment: I can ask my editor, but I am afraid he'll say no different than I do. Aside from that, DUDEN 10 (Bedeutungswörterbuch) contains only 20 000 entries that were selected from 4 million expressions of the entire DUDEN corpus. The *adverb trotzdem* is one of the lucky 20 000 selected entries; the *connector trotzdem* is not. Still, the latter exists and is used with the finite verb positioned at the end.

Comment: @user105071: I'm sorry, if 'connector' is not an accurate translation for Konnektor, you mayy roll it back, however you wouldn't put it in single quotes, but use italics to emphasize foreign language, if you feel the need to emphasize it at all. Towards the downvoting: The last time I looked it up, I was the user with an outstanding amount of downvotes, but still I have more upvotes than downvotes and I am far away from occupying over 50% of the downvotes, so your bets on me, being the downvoter, should be placed with care. But maybe you'll qualify for my downvote another time. ;)